# Can URL API endpoint self-correct?

Tags: reactjs, url, error-handling, try-catch, fetch-api

I am using fetch API inside a React application to retrieve and display some quiz questions.
This is my url endpoint: [https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=${amount}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple](https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=$%7Bamount%7D&difficulty=$%7Bdifficulty%7D&type=multiple)

I have noticed that:

-when I misspell part of the URL before "?" then the response doesn't get back.
example:[https://opentdb.com/api.ph?amount=${amount}&difficulty=${difficulty}&](https://opentdb.com/api.ph?amount=$%7Bamount%7D&difficulty=$%7Bdifficulty%7D&) (missing "p" of php)

-when I misspell part of the url after "?" then, sometimes I get an empty array back, sometimes I get the data back. How can I get data back with a wrong URL?
example: [https://opentdb.com/api.php?amoun=${amount}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple](https://opentdb.com/api.php?amoun=$%7Bamount%7D&difficulty=$%7Bdifficulty%7D&type=multiple) (missing "t" in amount)

I haven't deployed the application yet, I am using vsc and run npm start to develop the application.
Is it possible that the URL auto-corrects? or maybe it gets cached?

my code:

```
    export const fetchQuizQuestions = async (
  amount: number,
  difficulty: Difficulty
) => {
  const endPoint = `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=${amount}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(endPoint);
    console.log(response);

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (data.results.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("The part after ? contains some mistake");
    }
    //below I create the new property "all_answers" and make sure the answers order is never the same
    return data.results.map((question: Question) => ({
      ...question,
      all_answers: shuffleArray([
        ...question.incorrect_answers,
        question.correct_answer,
      ]),
    }));
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.name);
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `?` It's the url. So if you make a mistake there, basically it's like sending a letter to a different adress, so you will not get any answers.

After the `?` it's the query string. So you're asking for a result, with some parameters (your query)
So if you're saying like "ok, send me back answers with amount = XXX" but you misspell `amount`, it's just like "ok send me back answers" because you're not asking for `amount` anymore (but `amoun` which is nothing for the endpoint)

Comment: I have noticed though that if I misspell "amount" I get an error and no data, but If I misspell either "difficulty" or "type" the data come back with my parameters

Comment: depends on how the api is built. If `amount` is required and you misspell it, you've have an error because it is required. If you misspell a query which is not required, it's simply ignored

Comment: if I write "tpe=boolean" instead of "type=boolean" I still get the questions back in true/false format. I don't understand, from your answer, how is that possible?

Comment: ok I didn't know that there are required and non-required queries. What is a good source where I can read about API structure?

Comment: Again, depends on how the API is build, but you often have "default" values for query parameters, and I suppose the default value for `type` is `boolean`

Comment: If you use an external API, they often have a documentation with required and default fields. If it's your own, well you should know which are required, and what are the default values :)